# How to sort a Tuple using two parameters?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, tuples

A list of tuples contains `[('John',32),('Jane',22),('Doe',32),('Mario',55)]`. I want to sort the list by age and the same aged people by their names in alphabetical order ? So far I have used only Lambda function inside a sorted() function with key being either name or age ?

The output should be ->  `[('Jane',22),('Doe',32),('John',32),('Mario',55)]`.

Comment: `key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
>>> lot=[('John',32),('Jane',22),('Doe',32),('Mario',55)]
```

You can form a new tuple:

```
>>> sorted(lot, key=lambda t: (t[1],t[0]))
[('Jane', 22), ('Doe', 32), ('John', 32), ('Mario', 55)]
```

Or, in this case, you can reverse the tuple:

```
>>> sorted(lot, key=lambda t: t[::-1])
[('Jane', 22), ('Doe', 32), ('John', 32), ('Mario', 55)]
```

You can also use [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) with two arguments in the order you want the resulting key tuple to be:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(lot, key=itemgetter(1,0))
[('Jane', 22), ('Doe', 32), ('John', 32), ('Mario', 55)]
```

Comment: Thanks. I also found that in first solution inside we can use " - " for reversing. `key=lambda t:(t[1],-t[0])`